# Orthogonal Projections- not invertible A * A

Tags: orthogonality

One of my homework problems asks to find the matrices of orthogonal projections onto all four fundamental subspaces.

For the projection onto the range of the matrix, I used

projection of Range of A = A((A * A)inverse)A *.

But the A * A is not invertible, so I was wondering where to go from here? Is there a different equation I can use in this situation?

If anyone is curious, the matrix is

1 1 1

1 3 2

2 4 3

*I have figured out what my issue was, I needed an orthogonal basis. Now I have figured out the protection for Ran (A *) and Ran (A). By definition, Ran A = Ker( A *) Transpose, so does that mean Ran A transpose = Ker ( A *)?

Comment: what are the "four fundamental subspaces"?

Comment: Your formula only works when the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Start by finding a basis for the range of $A$.

Comment: What does Ran A mean? Range?